# extencion extension=oci8_12c php.ini laragon

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, laragon

Hola tengo ya varios dias con este problema tengo laragon con

Apache/2.4.54 (Win64)
OpenSSL/1.1.1q
PHP version: 7.3.0
quiero utilizar oracle en un proyecto que baje de mi repositorio

-instale instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0 en C:
descomente extension=oci8_12c en mi php.ini

pero al correrlo me marca error 500 despues reviso php_errors.log y me sale este error

[09-Aug-2023 17:49:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.3.0-nts-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\oci8_12c (No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.), C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.3.0-nts-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (No se puede encontrar el m�dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: (1) Verificar que [Oracle Instantclient](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) sea de la misma arquitectura que PHP: 32 bits con 32bits y 64 bits con 64 bits respectivamente. (2) Agregar la ruta de instantclient, por ejemplo `C:\instantclient_12_2`, a la variable de entorno PATH de Sistema. Verificar otras posibles entradas conflictivas en esas variables. (3) InstantClient_12_2 require tener instalado [VCredist 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170), de la misma arquitectura.

Comment: ya lo revise aun asi sigue mostrandome el error Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.3.0-nts-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\oci8_12c (No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.)

Comment: cuando instalas el modudo de oracle debes configurarlo manualmente, lo hiciste?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162636/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-oci8-12c